# I want to remove the duplicates without sorting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, duplicates

**Javascript:**

```
function Add(){
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
                var images = mydiv.getElementsByTagName("img");
                var dydiv = document.createElement("div");        


                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {              

                        var elem = document.createElement("img");
                        elem.setAttribute("src", images[i].src);
                        elem.setAttribute("height", "100%");
                        elem.setAttribute("width", "100%");
                        dydiv.appendChild(elem);

                    }
}
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="Add()" value="Add"/>

    <div id="mydiv">
      <asp:Repeater id="rpt" runat="server">
        <itemtemplate>
                <div >
                    <img src='<%#Eval("img")%>' alt="No Image" />
                </div>

         </temtemplate>
       </asp:Repeater> 


         </div>
```

Here I'm getting the duplicate values in Images array object. As there are 4 images, I am getting 8 images.(btw I don't understand why I am getting duplicates :-( ) Now I want to remove the duplicates without sorting. plz help me....

Comment: Maybe your function is getting called twice?

Comment: Please remove the `jquery` tag, since you're not using jQuery in here.

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/bGEVc/

Comment: In the code shown you create a div with some images, and then just throw it away. What do you do in the code not shown, where you use the elements created?

Comment: Yes, but when I use Repeater, this issue is occurring...

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/NLu5p/

Comment: I think the issue is with ASP rather than Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Hope this logic to remove duplicates from an array might help. I'm not saying to copy this and paste this. I just want to share the logic, and the rest I think you can figure it out.

```
var items = ["milk","bottle","mobile","cups","milk","screen","table", "toothpaste"];
var filteredItems= [];
$.each(items, function(i, element){
    if($.inArray(element, filteredItems) === -1) filteredItems.push(element);
});
```

The array :`filteredItems` will contain uniquevalues without sorting the original array..
Hope that serves you.

Comment: BUt I want to remove the Duplicate values from the Primary array(say items)

Comment: the thing I did is create a new set of array which will insert items in the same sequence as of old array, while inserting if it encounters any duplicates it skips the current and then goes with next element till end of array.. this is doing exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: This is more like a patch. There shouldn't be "duplicates." I know that was the original question, but from reading the question, it doesn't seem like there should be duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This may be because as you append images to your document, the images HTMLCollection (images) increases in size.

If I do `var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');`, I get an HTMLCollection containing all the elements that I looked for.

If I then go and do:

```
var newImage = document.createElement('img');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newImage);
```

The HTML collection now contains the new image as well.

What you may be trying to accomplish is changing the height, width and src of the image that already exists. In that case, you wouldn't have to create a new element and then append it, you could just loop over the HTMLCollection and change the height, width and src of the element in the HTMLCollection.

Comment: My issue is, Iam getting duplicate images here itself:var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');